# Did you know it was GNOME's birthday yesterday?

Tags: discussion

This is the first question I have asked, and I hope it this is not an inappropriate place for it ...
But I thought it was worth mentioning, sharing  and posting this picture I have.
 :o)

[Happy Birthday GNOME](http://happybirthdaygnome.org/)

*Version 1 of the GNU Network Object Model Environment(GNOME), from 1999.*

[image: t]

Comment: While this is great and we should all celebrate, it's off topic for Ask Ubuntu meta (and the main site). Ask Ubuntu meta is designed for the [following questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#questions). This is more of a discussion piece and would be better suited for [Chat](http://chat.askubuntu.com/), [IRC](http://ubuntu.com/community), or the [Forums](http://ubuntuforums.com).

Comment: @MarcoCeppi - Fair enough and apologies - sorry I should of known better :o(

Comment: No need for apologies! I'm sure chat would love to talk about this and celebrate there :)